# Change Different type of Attributes for Dynamically added every element

Tags: angularjs

How can I Change (type) Attribute for each added dynamic buttons? In below code, label names were changing perfectly, but when i am trying to change button types it is applying to all added dynamic buttons,
 My requirement is have to change every button type with different types (means: first added button type to submit, second added type to reset, third added button to cancel). but in my code if i change second button type to 'Reset' at the same time the first button type also going to Reset type... can u please tell me how can i change button type for every added element ...

[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6v28zBjw8Fts8kKEmC5?p=preview)

**Updated:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  var counter = 0;
        $scope.buttonFields = [];

  $scope.add_Button = function(index) {
  $scope.buttonFields[counter] = {button: 'Submit'};
        var buttonhtml = '<div ng-click="selectButton(buttonFields[\'' + counter + '\'])"><button id="button_Type">{{buttonFields[' + counter + '].button}}</button>//click//</div>';

        var button = $compile(buttonhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(button);

    $scope.changeTosubmit = function (val) {
        $scope.buttonField = val;
        var els = document.body.querySelectorAll('#button_Type');
        for (var i = 0, ils = els.length; i < ils; i++) {
            var el = els[i];
            el.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            compile(el);
        }
    };
    $scope.changeToreset = function (val) {
        $scope.buttonField = val;
        var els = document.body.querySelectorAll('#button_Type');
        for (var i = 0, ils = els.length; i < ils; i++) {
            var el = els[i];
            el.setAttribute("type", "reset");
            compile(el);
        }
    };
    $scope.changeTocancel = function (val) {
        $scope.buttonField = val;
        var els = document.body.querySelectorAll('#button_Type');
        for (var i = 0, ils = els.length; i < ils; i++) {
            var el = els[i];
            el.setAttribute("type", "cancel");
            compile(el);
        }
    };
        ++counter;
    };

    $scope.selectButton = function (val) {
        $scope.buttonField = val;
$scope.showButton_Types = true;
    };
  
});
function compile(element) {
var el = angular.element(element);
$scope = el.scope();
$injector = el.injector();
$injector.invoke(function ($compile) {
    $compile(el)($scope);
});
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Button($index)">Add Buttons</button>
<hr>
 <div id="add"></div>
 <form ng-show="showButton_Types">
      <div>
        <label>Button Name(?)</label><br/>    
        <input ng-model="buttonField.button">
      </div>
      <div>            
        <label>change button types(?)</label><br/>
<input ng-click="changeTosubmit(buttonFields['' + counter + ''])" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Submit
    <input ng-click="changeToreset(buttonFields['' + counter + ''])" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Reset
    <input ng-click="changeTocancel(buttonFields['' + counter + ''])" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Cancel
      </div>
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```